# Android Tablet - 3.0 Icon set/Guidelines

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-icons

The latest version of Android is 3.0 Honeycomb. Before this version, we are providing 3 resolutions images for the application,i.e. hdpi, mdpi and ldpi.

But, what are the icon resolutions for the 3.0 Honeycomb? or the same icon resolutions works with Honeycomb version as well. (Because tablet are of large screen i.e. Extra high density (320), xhdpi)

I have already gone through SDK: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, but failed to find solutions.

Comment: Well I think - this line itself says too much - `Tablets are not xhdpi, they are xlarge screens with mdpi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the xhdpi and xlarge qualifiers for the resources.

Also, the usual rule to know the size of an hdpi icon corresponding to a mdpi icon is to multiply by 1.5 the dimensions (because resolution is 1.5 times greater: 240dpi vs 160dpi). For tablets width xhdpi screens, you could apply the same calculation: multiply by 2 the dimensions of mdpi images (320dpi vs 160dpi).

Comment: Thanx for your great support and valuable information. But Right now if we target samsung galaxy tab, motorolla xoom tablets and other, then What may be a size of Splash Image, Action bar Tab and Menu icon ? please let me know. Thanx once again for your great support.

Comment: Tablets are not xhdpi, they are xlarge screens with mdpi.

Answer (score 1):

looking at the sources of honeycomb google uses 115x115px images for xhdpi with 8px outer boarder on all sides.